# Removing circle in CSS on hover

Tags: html, css, class

I'm trying to remove a circle that's made in CSS but when I remove a few lines using the same class it makes the magnifying glass on it bigger but I want it to stay the same size.

URL to the site: http://goo.gl/S0yQQ5  You can see the circle by hovering over a image.

The classes: mask, mask_circle

CSS: http://pastebin.com/szdyQRp9

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code here or your question will get closed.

Comment: give us fiddle what u have tried?

Comment: I'm using wordpress to run this on fiddle it's hard and I can't post the whole css here..

Comment: @GuusvanWalstijn Then post part of the code, where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Add this to your stylesheet:</strike>

```
.mask_circle { display: none; }
```

**[EDIT based on comments]**

If you want to keep the magnifying glass, but as a rectangle (not a circle), do this:

```
.one_fourth.gallery4:hover .mask .mask_circle {
    border-radius: 200px; /* delete this line */
```

Please note that there is also `.one_half`, `.one_third` styles in your stylesheet which give the `.mask_circle` inside those specific classes an rounded border. You'll need to change them all, if you use those styles too. Or you could do it the quick and dirty(!!) way:

```
.mask_circle {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: It did deleted the circle, but it also deleted the magnificent glass, and it isnt clickable anymore.

Comment: Should the magnifying glass be kept? Or deleted as well?

Comment: Its should be kept, and clickable

Comment: I have tried both of the options, but it will turn the circle into a square.

Comment: Yes... if that is not what you want, then please explain better!!

Comment: I want to remove the whole background so there is no square or circle just the magnifying glass on the image when I hover over it.

Comment: The image has a background. You should change the image to accomplish that... have you done anything to look for a solution, or just put the question up here...

Comment: Yes, I tried a few things I just need that circle removed. I removed the class from the css but that made the glass bigger. This is what I want: http://puu.sh/5Lfdh.png